# Am I being used more than my job role as a Graphic Designer?

Tags: project-management, productivity, teamwork, motivation, projects

I'm a Graphic Designer in a Digital marketing and design agency startup (8 months experience). I'm the only designer there. There's one person for copy writing and one director who checks my designs. There are no senior designers and art directors.

Whenever we have to make social media designs/ads for campaigns, I do the following: research, brainstorming, consider how to promote the product, how it affects the market, what its message should be (the actual message of campaign is decided *after* I have made the designs).

When I present these ideas to content team and director, their only response is, "Yes, try that".

Most of them time it works but sometimes it doesn't, so I work harder and smarter.

**Consider my current situation.** I present my concepts to my director,  he agrees, I make the designs, but he then immediately rejects them because he prefers the previous ideas. Okay, for the current product it wasn't possible to do that way. So, I researched further ideas but at the end result was the same.

I receive no support from my director and content team.  There is a lack of constructive feedback,  most of the time it's limited to "*try something different*" or "*I don't like it, try again*".  **(I'm not sure if I should expect this type of support and feedback)**

Often I am criticized for "wasting" time on ideas that prove to be unfeasible or unrealistic. Even after 3-4 attempts things work, I'm criticized like why I didn't think like this at the beginning.

---

At this point, I find myself questioning my role and skills as a Graphic Designer. The lack of specific directions and the multitude of expectations confuse me as I'm not confident this is the role of a Graphic Designer. As soon as I know what my job entails,  I'll be able to move forward in my career and make better choices in the future. But without knowing, I'm losing confidence in myself.

*(If you'd like to know the design problem, please read [HERE](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/126337/are-these-designs-just-images-and-not-relating-with-the-product-any-way) on Graphic Design SE).*

---

Given all that I know, I realize that somewhere there is a fault.

1. The missing specific communication/feedback from my director, which results in every type of expectations and roles from me.
2. There should be an art director who can help the way I want (Again, I don't know much about their responsibilities much). Currently I'm handling everything including Graphic Design.
3. As I'm the only Graphic Designer there, I have to take full responsibility. **A Graphic Designer has to research what will work best for the public, decide what the campaign message is, know the market, how to promote the product, and what theme to follow (e.g., Monsoon based, Cricket World Cup based etc.)**
4. I'm in a wrong startup among the wrong people. The expectations of my role are far greater than I currently understand them to be. They are using me as Art Director + Graphic Designer
5. Something else?

I've mentioned these points, but I'm not fully sure if I'm right.

I'm not afraid of my ideas being rejected or of working overtime. I feel bad only when I begin doubting my design skills, and what is my job role.  **If I have a clearer idea of what my role is,  I'll be able to take better decisions about my career, for example discussing my job role with my director.**

I understand that my problem may appear to be self-focused but I would like to know the answer in terms of what usually happens in other companies. **When you're not an art director/project manager**, how moral is it to expect most of the project related things from you, when you're a Graphic Designer?

As a Graphic Designer in most of the digital marketing and design agency, do I have to take responsibility for the entire campaign? Am I being used more than my role demands? Is it normal that I should handle everything almost single-handedly?

Comment: Seems to me that you are the implicit art director, and being the sole Designer makes you the senior

Comment: I just read through your post on Graphic Design SE and I want to share my 2 cents with you: The imgs you chose would be a better fit for an insurance company since rain and heavy weathers are rather associated with general dangers and an umbrella are ass. with protection rather than the far-fetched analogies you've made in interpreting the customers perception. My suggestion is that you read more about marketing psychology - there are numerous good publications out there. Also try to achieve more obvious & suitable correlations between the imgs and the customers interpretation. Good luck ;)

Comment: VTC, totally unclear what is being asked for.  Yes you have to deal with it either by internalizing it or working to change the situation.  Same as any other adversity in your life.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96046/discussion-between-vks-and-myles).

Comment: Completely outside my domain, but, if I were you, I think I'd start calling myself the Art Director and Graphic Designer. Maybe it'll stick. Then, just keep working at it all until you're more comfortable.

Comment: @Vikas Who has what duties and what titles is company specific. See closure reason "Questions seeking company-specific advice on workplace regulations or policies, or legal advice".  If someone comes saying "I'm a computer programmer, do I have to handle book keeping at this startup?" the correct action from the community would be to close this question because we can't tell you an answer for your specific business with it's unique business requirements.  Title and exact duties do not have a 1 to 1 correlation.

Comment: For better answers, the question needs improvement. In a few bullet points, what is the situation? In one sentence, what, specifically, is the desired improvement or change? @Vikas, if you can edit this down to a short (5 bullet points + 2-3 sentences) version, you'll get better answers. There's just too much here to consider and comment on.

Comment: I'll try that @Jay

Comment: @Myles @ Jay should I ask this question again with removing the problems discussed here widely? Or should I edit this only?

Comment: I'll be honest.  I have no idea what it is that you're actually looking for here.   What is your question?    Please be specific.

Comment: @Mari-LouA so this question can't be answered? Shall I delete it?

Comment: @Keith it's clearly mentioned here. At the end you'll see 1-2 simple queries, that's what I want answers for : ( But ridiculous response here for such a genuine problem.

Comment: "*so this question can't be answered? Shall I delete it?*" You cannot delete a question, even if you wanted to, once it has received an answer and that answer has been upvoted. And this question has received six answers so far. I don't understand why you think the question has changed so much that it now invalidates these answers. Woodie 2714's answer offers some good advice about taking notes and then his/her suggestion to look for another employment implies that the company is perhaps exploiting your role. By the way have you talked to Human Resources? Is that a good idea??

Comment: @Mari-LouA we don't have HR. Even if I had, it's not that big company. I believe people know more here.

Comment: @Mari-LouA yes there are 6 answers. But there are 6 down votes also, for this question. Clearly question is incorrect, so I can't decide whether answers do justify here or not.

Comment: I think the downvotes were used to convey the message that the question was unclear to begin with. Then once the question was reopened, I think, the following DVs were because you reversed an edit by Myles, who was trying to help, who by the way is not a moderator. Moderators on SE have a diamond next to their name.  I don't think your question is incorrect = bad, but I do sense quite a bit of anxiety and confusion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA the last edit by some guy has improved it. No?

Comment: You could visit Workplace. meta and ask the community why your post currently has 12 downvotes and only 6 upvotes (-6 is the visible score). Don't accuse anyone of not understanding or of being unfair. Emphasis the fact that you want to IMPROVE the question so that it can help future visitors and other graphic designers. **P.S** Erm, the last guy  who edited is me! :) Give it some time, the bounty still has five days

Comment: Let me ask it there @Mari-LouA

Comment: @Mari-LouA those 5 days will bring 10-15 more down votes.

Comment: *those 5 days will bring 10-15 more down votes.* Don't be so pessimistic. Users on Workplace are generally supportive.

Comment: I have added a question on meta.

Comment: What do you mean Director? Creative Director? Company Director?

Comment: @user70848 Company director, with a specialty in content writing. They also review my designs.

Comment: KEEP DOWN VOTING GUYS, KEEP IT UP, if that makes you happy >.<

Comment: Are you asking if it’s reasonable to expect you to do work that’s not in your job description? Or are you asking for strategies to get better feedback for your designs? If you’re asking both, split the question: ask one here and write another question about the other.

Comment: @user70848 2nd thing is kind of dependent on 1st thing. Also, *asking if it’s reasonable to expect you to do work that’s not in your job description?* Not really, instead: Am I doing more than my job role and is it normal to do it when compared with most other companies (excluding top companies like Micrsoft, Google, Apple etc)?

Comment: I think these questions will stand on their own, but you can reference another question if more context is needed. As written, what you have is too complicated to get a straightforward answer. Focus on one thing and cut out everything else.

Answer (score 7):

Does your boss give you any feedback? If he did and you didn't follow the advice then it's kind of your fault but if he just said *"No, its crap do it again"* then you should probably find a new job.

Also by what you have written it seems that your boss okays the concept but then rejects the final product, maybe try working on the concept a little longer before showing it to your boss. This way he may find a reason to reject this idea before you spend more time completing the design.

When you show the concept to your boss make notes about what he says, ask him which bits he likes, dislikes, thinks are fine. Also ask him *"What would you do differently?"* or *"How would you improve this?"*.

If he doesn't engage in this kind usefull evaluation and analysis then he sounds like an unreasonable person and you should start looking for a job where you will be able to improve your craft and contribute to the business.

Comment: @iLuvLogix thanks for fixing my numerous gramatical errors

Comment: You are welcome ;)

Comment: I like the things you said. These will be helpful. And yes it's just like *No, its crap do it again*.

Comment: Also, I quite didn't get your 2nd paragraph. You mean I should spend more time on the brainstorming the concept before start making the design actually? If yes, it will result in same thing. Overall, I will get same feedback i.e., you've spent so much time!

Comment: > "No, its crap do it again" then you should probably find a new job.
This may be a warning flag for mature companies, but it happens often in startups. There are many more problems than people, and oversight can be lacking.

Comment: @VKS no make a start on the actual designs and show them to your boss when they are partially completed so then if he rejects the idea you haven't wasted time completing the design. also is it only you that hes saying "no, its crap do it again" to? if so its possible this guy just hates you and is trying to get you fired by saying you are useless, so I would also find someone else in an equal or higher position than him to show your designs to.

Comment: @Woodie2714 no, they need me. And also I'm only designer there with a less salary and comparatively better skills. They don't want to fire me soon.

Comment: @Vikas if they need you that is all the more reason to quit. personally I would say in a exit interview that your manager made you feel that your work wasn't valued and you weren't progressing professionally. might get them to look into this managers behaviour

Comment: After the edits, it doesn't match my question. The fundamental question remains unanswered.

Comment: @Vikas it does sound like you are doing a lot of work for a graphic designer. also doing that kind of creative work alone is always more difficult than with a team. personally I find it really helpful to bounce my ideas off someone else, get somekind of feedback loop and like you said you aren't getting any feedback. personally it seems like you are doing a lot of work, then being told "this is crap, fix it" without being told why its crap or how to fix it. Honestly, polish your CV and run, that place must be soo stressful to work in, your health is worth more than a job.

Answer (score 4):

From a graphic designer with similar experience. A sole GD cannot be expected to produce a fresh/unique/outstanding project. You might get the odd idea here and there but the job burden is just to much to execute them.
I would advise to look for, what I consider, red flags:

- are they giving you any feedback (and "fix it" "not like that" "something different" is not feedback)
- is the feedback applicable? So can you cut it into pieces that can be used in pushing the design further. So leave the design as it is but change font, or photo etc.
- And more important - is the person who meet with client acting as a gate keeper? So if they pass 1:1 what you have done to client and vice versa or do they say "client didn't like it"?

After looking at your question on GD.SE: Are you sure you are a graphic designer there? It looks like you are doing a role of Art Director but without an account manager and brief. IMHO in brief you should have emphasised things you need to use and keep them in mind when creating a design for the client.
Also what has been written on GD.SE is THE THING that your director should tell you OR it's what client should point out.

Personal notes: your designs and overall production quality are fine. You just made ads for multivitamins and immunity enhancers instead of asthma drugs.

**Answering question after edit:** Yes, you are used as more than just Graphic Designer. But you shouldn't take blame for everything. Manager/boss/owner should be aware of the fact that you cannot handle everything, everytime in the best possible way and either you would need more support (in the form of short brief for example) or you should be given some slack.
Mind reading and expectation of it is a terrible trait in manager especially when you are a sole recipient of it.
I would ask if before doing anything you could sit together and make a short brief for yourself (and maybe for the client? It would be faster and easier for them to correct written word than critique finished work).

Comment: You caught the right point. They give exactly same feedback which is actually not feedback. Mostly they say "something different".

Here I quite didn't get your second bullet point, maybe I'm not that good in English. Basically, once my director likes the design, they send it to the client online. The client sometimes like it and sometimes reject it. Client gives feedback to my director and is forwarded to me. So would you please let me know what you wanted ask in 2nd bullet point?

Comment: I've edit my question. Kindly check, made it clear and answerable. Would you like to tweak your answer now?

Comment: @VKS I added an answer. Regarding my second bullet point what I had in mind is "can the feedback relate to what you show?". "something different" is not one. Applicable would mean that they are ok with font but not the color. Or they like the text placement but would change people on photo. I like to use metaphor of balls. If you have steel one you can say it's too cold, or to silver or too shiny. There is something you know what would need to be changed.

Comment: @ SZCZERZO KŁY really sorry for a misunderstanding. Actually I got your 2nd point but I was talking about 3rd. By mistake I wrote 2nd. I didn't get the bullet point about 1:1. I hope you won't mind explaining it here :)

Comment: @Vikas What I meant is if comments/critique/request from client are passed to you without any change OR are they boiled down to "client didn't liked". There are two option if the second. First is that client really had no input BUT then person meeting with them should work with them to get anything to help you make better work (you cannot read minds) or second option they are withholding information from you and deciding by themselves that "it's bad" is what client said and is enough for you as a feedback.

Comment: it's more like your last line in above comment. In earlier days I've always believed and told my director 1-2 times that we should communicate with client better so we do better. But I guess my directors feel they know better than client. Important thing. For most of the designs, client doesn't have a specific need. We decide it. I think this is also a reason for expecting me to do all things. I don't have much information from directors to work on. So I'm deciding most of the things.

Comment: @Vikas and that might be the problem. You are acting as half of the account manager and art director but without contacting client personally. So a) you cannot get your idea behind your work to the client b) you are not given client idea. Your director is working as a jammer not as a relay. Maybe ask for meeting with clients to prepare short briefs?

Answer (score 3):

I do not know the design world so I will try to see this more as a project management situation.

> As a Graphic Designer in a digital marketing and design agency, do I
>   have to deal with it, doesn't matter it's too bad for you and your
>   self esteem?

You will always deal with undecided people, your goal is to understand the need and find a work-around the undecision. It's not simple and it can be surely frustrating but it's part of the job, especialy if you're in a small start up. You have an opportunity to fully manage your project on your own, get the experience for later in your carrier.

> Or there's something else which can be improved, and which can improve
>   whole situation?

You can discuss this with your director/content team. How can you make it easier for everyone ? When I have a client that is struggling with his idea and doesn't really know what he wants, I work with him step by step. I put him at the center of the projet so that he can build his idea as I develop it. Is is possible for you to work like this when you notice it's gonna be a hard one ? Again, design is not really my thing...

Comment: The point is, I'm ready to learn those extra skills. I'm already doing them. I just wanted to know if I'm the person to be fully blamed here. Is it totally my fault?

Comment: I've edit my question. Kindly check, made it clear and answerable. Please edit your answer if you think :)

Comment: You surely have a lot of responsibility but, you are not to be fully blamed here. There's clearly a lack of communication and good feedback. They can't expect you to do some miracles in these conditions.

Comment: After the edits, it doesn't match my question. The fundamental question remains unanswered.

Answer (score 2):

I hate to say this, but I have to: Your question is off.

If your company were a big company, like Amazon, Apple or Facebook, yes, the question makes perfect sense. You want to have a clear definition of your job role, you want to have some artists working with you so you can come up with better products.

Unfortunately, you work for a start-up. Every start-up has its own style, its own way to deal with business. Some startup is like a mini Amazon, I saw one before. They have a sales dept, a design dept. an engineering dept and an accounting dept and some other departments. Guess what, the CEO is the director of three departments and the CEO's wife is in charge of accounting and design.

The answer you are expecting may or may not exist in the company you work for. I think you are asking too much.

My suggestion, stick with what you have now and try to improve the situation by communicating with your boss, or quit and look for a company that suits your idea about what a graphic designer should be.

Comment: Your answer is off. *You want to have a clear definition of your job role, you want to have some artists working with you so you can come up with better products* No! Please read my question again.

Comment: There's a reason I've put so much details.

Comment: @Vikas I already read your question before I wrote the answer. Your problem is simple, you lack of support and colleagues to collaborate the design so your boss put the blame on you and you don't know what to do next. Typical problem in startup. One person to do many people's job. You want to do it, stay. you don't want to do it, quit. Simple as that. My answer is another way to say it.

Comment: But it doesn't answer according to the details I've put in bounty's comment.

Comment: @Vikas I am not answering for the bounty. In my opinion, the question should be closed because it's company specific. As I said in the answer, _Every start-up has its own style, its own way to deal with business_. This is like everybody looks different (twins are the exceptions). You expect to have a general answer. Based on my experience(+30 yrs career), there is no general one. You just have to deal with it on company by company basis. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

> They are using me as Art Director + Graphic Designer

Absolutely this. No one is in charge of direction and you lead the creative effort. They are expecting you to *deal* with things to the best of your ability, which means taking more creative direction and owning your results.

This is par for the course for young startups-- people often wear many hats, and direct mentorship is usually not available. Don't think about this situation in the context of titles, think about it in the context of the work that needs to be done, and who is best suited to do it.

By the way, its totally ok to be uncomfortable in this situation, with added responsibility and increased workload, as startup life is not for everyone. On the other hand, if you enjoy more responsibility and stretching your wings into direction and project management, then I suggest you abandon the idea that you have a traditional manager and treat these people as peers: by endlessly helpful, minimize the amount of stuff they have to worry about, and go looking for problems to solve.

> I'm hold responsible and blamed for all (time spent, rejections), without any support and a direction to begin solving the problem.

Exactly what I'd expect from a startup. I don't have any advice for dealing with the confidence issues if you're just starting out except that talent, grit, and a deep passion either for your work or your venture help a lot. The feeling of inadequacy and uncertainty **will** go away, but expect higher levels of stress until then and probably after. If you can get through the hard parts, you stand to gain large professional and personal growth.

Comment: I've edit my question. Kindly check, made it clear and answerable. Please edit your answer if you think :)

Comment: It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I'm answering quoted parts of your question directly. "When you're not an art director/project manager, how moral is it to expect most of the project related things from you, when you're a Graphic Designer?" Its nothing to do with morality-- its a startup, and you're being pushed to take more responsibility where there's no one currently handling those things. This is normal in small companies: you can either seize the opportunity or find another company with better defined roles.

Comment: If you had 5k+ reputations, I would believe you. So I'm more dependent on others :) It's my nature, good or bad I don't know.

Comment: Heh, my answer is not a reflection of my Workplace experience, it comes from my professional experience: I'm currently on my 5th startup. Despite the downvotes, I think you ask a good question that other people will also ask. What you do with my answer is your prerogative.

Answer (score 1):

Some things leapt out at me in the question:

> I'm the only designer there. There's one person for copy writing and one director who checks my designs. There are no senior designers and art directors.

and:

> There should be an art director who can help the way I want (Again, I don't know much about their responsibilities much). Currently I'm handling everything including Graphic Design.

In smaller organizations this notion of having a broader scope than what your title alone may imply is going to be very much the norm. I'm not a graphic designer myself but I've worked with more than a few - both in-house design teams and where we were an agency providing services to third parties. While all were relatively small (ranging from 12 employees to a couple of thousand) not a single one of them ever had an "Art Director" and in the majority of cases a good chunk of what you are considering extraneous to your role would have been very much expected of someone with the "Graphic Designer" title.

> I receive no support from my director and content team. There is a lack of constructive feedback, most of the time it's limited to "try something different" or "I don't like it, try again". (I'm not sure if I should expect this type of support and feedback)

This sucks. And I feel for you, I really do. But sadly it's all too common - taking as an example a web design/digital marketing firm I worked for some years back I'd say that over a third of the clients would give similar "feedback". It drove the designers nuts! But it was (and most likely remains) part of the game - and being able to draw out the right requirements from a client (be they external or internal) and therefore deliver what the client wanted even if they weren't good at articulating that is a really valuable skill for a designer. Executing those requirements well is only part of the job!

> I'm in a wrong startup among the wrong people. The expectations of my role are far greater than I currently understand them to be.

This hits the nail on the head IMO - they aren't "wrong" for wanting a role to do all you describe, but you aren't "wrong" for that not being a role you want either. I've known designers who would hate there being another person that took those elements from them and visa versa. So to answer this:

> When you're not an art director/project manager, how moral is it to expect most of the project related things from you, when you're a Graphic Designer?

It's totally "moral" for them to expect these things, but it's totally moral for you not to be okay with that for **you**.

> I'm not afraid of my ideas being rejected or of working overtime. I feel bad only when I begin doubting my design skills, and what is my job role. If I have a clearer idea of what my role is, I'll be able to take better decisions about my career, for example discussing my job role with my director.

It sounds like you need to have a frank discussion with your boss about how they see the role - if it's too far from how you see it and you can't find a compromise that works for both parties then it's probably time to move on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your complaint is that you're doing a lot of work solo, without your colleagues actively contributing.

A lack of collaboration is likely driven by combination of (a) your own behavior, (b) the processes of your team and (c) the attitudes of your colleagues. Put the greatest effort into what you directly control - your behavior.

---

(a) **Your own behavior has a strong impact on whether or not others want to collaborate with you and contribute to projects you're working on.** If your colleagues feel valued and trusted when they work with you, they will enjoy contributing to your work.  If your colleagues feel belittled or criticized when they offer an idea to you, they will avoid working with you.

---

(b) Additionally, there are potentially some process improvements that might help boost collaboration - **consider what you can personally do to make it easy for your colleagues to contribute:**

1. **Invite others to participate in brainstorming.** During the brainstorming phase, invite your colleagues to join - ideally in a room with a big white board. Prompt the group with the issue and invite them to start throwing out ideas - anything that comes to mind. Write down everything, never dismiss or re-word an idea, regardless of how strange. Offer your own ideas *last*. Let the group pick several favorites to pursue.
2. **Make your in-process work available for review.** Make it super-easy for someone to see your work very early in the process in case they have ideas or feedback. Post sketches/ideas that you've been developing on a wall in the office or a meeting room. Let your team know what project the work is for and that you welcome any feedback.
3. **Actively collaborate with the copy writer.** Ask him/her for a few minutes every day to check in on the projects you're working on together. Show him/her the design and ask him/her for ideas about the copy and to share any copy that might be in process. Be ready to change your designs to match his/her ideas.
4. **Find time to debrief each project with the full team that was involved.** Ask the account manager to share feedback from the client. Invite the team to share what they think went well and what could have been improved. Keep track of both the strengths of the team and ideas for improvement.

---

(c) **Trying to change your teammates isn't going to accomplish much.** The most you can do is directly ask for feedback and contributions from your colleagues and let them know how you feel when they don't contribute.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's more of an advice, which would be helpful, but not the answer.

Comment: @Vikas, your question should include a goal. What is the goal you are trying to accomplish in *your* workplace? See: https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2696#2696

Comment: Goal: To give my best as a Graphic Designer, only if 1) handing all things is the responsibility of a Graphic Designer in most (say 70% companies) of the companies AND 2) My salary is increased (current salary is too less as compared to offers my other same level companies)

Comment: @Vikas, then I suggest posting two new questions. One should be about how to clarify the responsibilities of a graphic designer with your management. The second should be about negotiating a better salary (or see the many existing questions about negotiating a raise).

Comment: I don't believe in clarifying it with my current management. The question is about myself and my future and what happens in most other companies (excluding top level companies like Microsoft, Google, Apple etc.). My management expects everything from me. I'm not afraid of handling all things. I'm already doing it. For me, if doing X and doing Y were duties of a job, I would do it no matter how much work is there (salary thing would come second).  Does it make sense now?